# How to remove a oracle user in a shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

I have requirement where in,I need to remove a oracle user and this should be done in a shell script.I am new to both sql and shell scripting.I am using below script but not able to remove the user.Can any one help me out

```
#!/bin/sh
su - oracle;
sqlplus as / sysdba;
startup force;
drop user SM cascade;
```

Comment: *sqlplus as / sysdba;* is wrong. It should be `sqlplus / as sysdba`

Comment: Hi Kumar thanks,I tried that ,but still not able to delete the user

Comment: Redirect the responses into a logfile, and show the content here.

Comment: SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Fri Feb 6 17:48:08 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


Enter user-name:

Comment: Isn't is clear enough looking at the error? You couldn't even connect to database.

Comment: I got it,but now my question is even though I logged in as sysdba,why it is saying insufficient privileges

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70370/discussion-between-praveen-and-lalit-kumar-b).

Comment: You haven't got it; the ORA-01031 is because you cannot connect to the database, it isn't getting as far as trying to drop the user. And if you did comnect your startup and drop are currently shell commands, not SQL\*Plus commands. Does the `su`  step even work? You're running SQL\*Plus is running *after* that so you are no longer the Oracle user by then.

Comment: See [**How to resolve sqlplus / as sysdba : ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/11/03/sqlplus-as-sysdba-ora-01031-insufficient-privileges/)

Answer (score 4):

You're running a series of commands in the shell, but they are not connected. Your `su` starts a new shell as the Oracle user, but then exits and your script continues as the original user. You then try to run SQL*Plus as that original user, and (with the command corrected) that OS user doesn't have permission to connect as SYSDBA - that is protected. And the startup/drop commands won't run until SQL*Plus has exited, when they are also just (invalid) shell commands.

Conceptually you want something more like this; running SQL*Plus as an `su` *command* rather than a shell, and using a 'heredoc' to give SQL commands:

```
#/bin/sh
su - oracle -c sqlplus -s -l / as sysdba << !EOF
drop user SM cascade;
exit;
!EOF
```

The startup command seems rather out of place there so I've left it out, but you can run whatever commands you like before the `!EOF` marking the end of the heredoc.

But mixing `su` with a heredoc may not work ("standard in must be a tty"?) depending on your environment. You can put everything except the `su - oracle -c` in a script instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlplus -s -l / as sysdba <<!EOF
drop user SM cascade;
exit;
!EOF
```

and call *that* from the command line with `su - oracle -c "<path to your script>"`, but your script then needs to be visible to and executable by the Oracle account.

Having a script lying around that will drop a user, especially with cascade, seems rather dangerous; all too easy to run it accidentally at some point, maybe years later, maybe wiping out a lot of important data. I imagine this is just an example but it doesn't really seem like something you'd script at all, particularly for a normal user to be able to run whenever they like.

Comment: Also, why startup force in this script? It's an unsupported command and generally unwise to use;  it issues a shutdown abort to the database. Why would you want to do that?